# Yes/No Attribute determines if another attribute is visible

Tags: magento, attributes

I need some help figuring out how to configure an attribute.

I am trying to make something like this:

Is your hair color black (dropdown or radio button will show Yesor No)
If No is selected, a drop down list of (Blonde, Brown, Red, Other) will now be available, so the shopper can select one of those options.
If the shopper originally selected Yes, then the (blonde, brown, red, other) list will be not be available to select.

So, I will have a Yes/No attribute that determines if a List attribute will be visible/selectable or not.
If Yes is selected, the List attribute will not be visible/selectable
If No is selected, the List attribute will be visible/selectable

This is basically attaching an attribute to an attribute.

Thank for your help!

Comment: Hi, you mean on frontend product page, to let user configure its product, first element and if Yes a second element, else just one or in the backend when creating a product ?